How to calculate the probability of this order-related game?
A, B two people have four cards, each card is labeled with a number, A's card was labeled with the number 1, 3, 5, 7, B's card was labeled with the number 2, 4, 6, 8, two people for four rounds of competition.
In each round of the competition, each of the two people from their own holdings in the card randomly selected a card, and to compare the size of the number of the selected card on the size of the number of the number of people with large numbers scored 1, the number of people with small numbers scored 0 points. Then each discard the card selected in this round (discarded cards in the subsequent rounds can not be used).
How to calculate the probability that the total score of A is not less than 2 after four rounds of competition?
I think the probability is related to the card order. A scores 0 is easy to think(P=1/24). I have tried to discuss which turn A scores 1, but it's too complicated to analyse.
The answer shows $P=0.5$(but no hint), which also wonders me. It's easy to find that A may scores $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and B $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Is there some kind of symmetry in this problem?

Since only the card by card matchups matter, you can assume that $A's$ cards are in ascending order.  Now you just need to count the possible orders for $B's$ cards that give $A$ a score of $0$ or $1$.
